# AngularJS: drag-and-drop directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

I want do some modification with code or with directive to allow:

1. Limit dragging only vertically(by Y axis)
2. Make possible to pick up item for dragging only in one place of the
   element.

I'm using implementation of this directive. https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

```
<ul dnd-list="list.value" 
    class="list-group" 
    dnd-allowed-types="['entry']"
    dnd-dragover="overItem()"
    >

    <li ng-repeat="entry in list.value"
        dnd-draggable="entry"
        dnd-moved="list.value.splice($index, 1)"
        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
        dnd-type="'entry'"
        dnd-dragstart="selectedItem(entry, list.value)">
        <div>
            <div class="numeric-column">{{$index + 1}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-5">{{entry.id}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-5">{{entry.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code working fine.

**Question:** can i restrict `li` element to move only verticaly.

**Example:** http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Well .. it's a nice specification you've given us, what part of your code isn't working?

Comment: @sirrocco ok, agreed that description compressed. Code working fine. No complains about this directive. Question is: how I can extend this directive to not allow even drag element out of droppable container?